# srcset and viewport width

Tags: html, responsive-design, srcset

I have 2 images: one desktop version, one mobile version.
I would like the desktop image to be replaced by the mobile image when the viewport width resizes below 480px, just as would with the following CSS with background-image property :

```
.logo { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x200&amp;text=desktop); }
media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x150&amp;text=mobile); }
}
```

I thought I could achieve this with the srcset HTML attribute :

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200&amp;text=desktop" alt="" srcset="http://placehold.it/300x150&amp;text=mobile 480w">
```

But it does not work, the browser shows the mobile image all the time and rescales it on viewport resize, but I wish the 2 images remains in their respective original size.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior with srcset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do "art direction", i.e. the images are different more than just the smaller being scaled down version of the bigger image. If so, you need to use the `picture` element.

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="http://placehold.it/300x150&amp;text=mobile"
         media="(max-width: 480px)">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200&amp;text=desktop" alt="...">
</picture>
```

However, if your small image is actually a scaled-down version of the bigger image, then you can use `srcset`, but then you have no control over which image gets chosen. It's up to the browser to pick the best one based on screen density, network conditions, user preference, browser cache, etc.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200&amp;text=desktop"
     srcset="http://placehold.it/400x200&amp;text=desktop 400w,
             http://placehold.it/300x150&amp;text=mobile 300w"
     sizes="(max-width: 480px) 300px, 400px">
```

Note: If `srcset` is used and the larger image candidate is in cache, Chrome will always display this cached image candidate - no matter of the actual viewport size.