# img with srcset displays one image no matter the viewport size

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

There are two images

- red image of size 1000px
- green image of size 600px

I would like to use `srcset` in `img` tag to display images as follows:

- for viewport smaller or equal to 600px display the green image
- for viewport larger than 600px display the red image

This is the `img` tag:

```
<img 
sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 1000px"
srcset="http://i.imgur.com/YF2BCoe.png 1000w, http://i.imgur.com/aLdqQYI.png 600w"
/>
```

However, the images are displayed a bit randomly no matter the viewport size, and the red displays much more often, even for small viewport size.

fiddle (works in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/pakuonky/

What's wrong with the tag?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/29495023/729033 answer your question?

Comment: If I change the size 100vw to 600px in the fiddle, analogically to the linked solution, the fiddle behaves better. For viewport size less that 600px it still displays the red image but only for the first time. After resizing (but keeping under 600px) it displays always the green one. Maybe it's something with jsfiddle itself, I must test it on a normal page.